# Creating NSImage from NSColor

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a `NSPopUpButton` which contains a list of colors. In front of the color title, I need to display a small box of the same color (*maybe an image of same color*). So, I was thinking that if I can create an `NSImage` using `NSColor` (*which will be already present*), then I can use the `-[NSMenuItem setImage:]` method to display the image in front of the color title in the popup button.

So, how can I create an `NSImage` using `NSColor`?

Any other approaches to solve the problem are also welcome. :)

Comment: This should be what you are looking for:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990976/how-to-create-a-colored-1x1-uiimage-on-the-iphone-dynamically][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990976/how-to-create-a-colored-1x1-uiimage-on-the-iphone-dynamically

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A simple category method will do this

```
@interface NSImage (ImageAdditions)

+(NSImage *)swatchWithColor:(NSColor *)color size:(NSSize)size;


@end

@implementation NSImage (ImageAdditions)

+(NSImage *)swatchWithColor:(NSColor *)color size:(NSSize)size
{
    NSImage *image = [[[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:size] autorelease];
    [image lockFocus];
    [color drawSwatchInRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
    [image unlockFocus];
   return image;    
}

@end
```

**[EDIT]** remove deprecated API

Comment: `– setScalesWhenResized:` is **deprecated**. *This method was related to caching behavior. In Mac OS X v10.6 and later image caching is no longer necessary and as a result there is no replacement necessary.*

Answer (score 14):

If you're using AppKit, here's a Swift 5 convenience initializer version of the other answers. Sadly, this doesn't work in UIKit

```
extension NSImage {
    convenience init(color: NSColor, size: NSSize) {
        self.init(size: size)
        lockFocus()
        color.drawSwatch(in: NSRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
        unlockFocus()
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
let redSwatchImage = NSImage(color: .red, size: NSSize(width: 128, height: 128))
```

Feel free to change the semantics as necessary

Answer (score 7):

And the swift extension variant of above:

```
import Cocoa

extension NSImage {
  class func swatchWithColor(color: NSColor, size: NSSize) -> NSImage {
    let image = NSImage(size: size)
    image.lockFocus()
    color.drawSwatchInRect(NSRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
    image.unlockFocus()
    return image
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've wanted to do this so much that I made a little Swift package for it: [**Swift Color Swatches**](https://github.com/RougeWare/Swift-Color-Swatches).

It's used like this:

```swift
import ColorSwatches

// If you prefer to use a factory initializer on the image type:
let nsImagePurple1 = NSImage.swatch(color: .systemPurple)
let uiImagePurple1 = UIImage.swatch(color: .systemPurple)

// If you prefer to use an instance method on a color instance:
let nsImagePurple2 = NSColor.systemPurple.swatch()
let uiImagePurple2 = UIColor.systemPurple.swatch()
```

You can also pass a size to these if the default doesn't work for you