# NSMenuItem image color becomes dark when selected

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsmenuitem, nspopupbutton

I am using NSPopUpButton with title and image. Below is my code:

```
[self.popup addItemWithTitle:@"Parag"];
[[self.popup lastItem] setImage:[NSImage swatchWithColor:[NSColor greenColor] size:NSMakeSize(10.0, 10.0)]];
```

[Creating NSImage from NSColor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11225174/944634)

```
@interface NSImage (ImageAdditions)

+(NSImage *)swatchWithColor:(NSColor *)color size:(NSSize)size;


@end

@implementation NSImage (ImageAdditions)

+(NSImage *)swatchWithColor:(NSColor *)color size:(NSSize)size
{
    NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:size];
    [image lockFocus];
    [color drawSwatchInRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
    [image unlockFocus];
    return image;
}

@end
```

Color of image becomes dark if I select popup button:

[image]

Comment: Works correctly under mojave

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use NSRectFill to draw the color to the image? As far as I know, drawSwatchInRect does some alpha compositing.

```
@implementation NSImage (ImageAdditions)

+(NSImage *)swatchWithColor:(NSColor *)color size:(NSSize)size
{
    NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:size];
    [image lockFocus];
    [color set];
    NSRectFill(NSMakeRect(0, 0, size.width, size.height));
    [image unlockFocus];
    return image;
}

@end
```

Comment: Same issue. I think its because of selection layer on popup button.